# Using returned values in async await in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, asynchronous, async-await

So I am trying to access thermostatRow and the consts defined within it in another function, and I am trying to test that it is working by logging the const within that function so I know I can break it down into its different parts and push those parts into arrays as needed.

I tried 3 things, 2 of them are in my below code examples and the 3rd one returned `Promise { <pending> }` but I can't find that example.

```
 const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("sheet1"); 
// worksheet is defined in another function earlier in the file that is called  asynchronously before this one. 
    async function dataFormat(worksheet) {
      csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");
      await csvWorkbook.then(async function() {
        let restarts = 0;
        let nullCounts = true;
        let thermostatRows = [];
        // don't create arrays of current temp here ! do it in a diff function
        // const [serial,date,startDate,endDate,thing3,thing4,thing5] = firstTemps

    worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
      if (rowNumber > 6) {
        thermostatRows.push((row.values));
      }
    });
    thermostatRows.map(thermostatRow => {
      [,date,time,SystemSetting,systemMode,calendarEvent,ProgramMode,coolSetTemp,HeatSetTemp,currentTemp,currentHumidity,outdoorTemp,windSpeed,coolStage1,HeatStage1,Fan,DMOffset,thermostatTemperature,thermostatHumidity,thermostatMotion] = thermostatRow
      return thermostatRow// Push current temps , heatset and cool set into seperate arrays and use those arrays to run the overheat() function
    })
  })
};

const dataResult = async (worksheet) => {
  let result = await dataFormat(worksheet);
  console.log(result);
}
```

This logs nothing.

So I also tried:

```
const dataResult = async () => {
  let result = await dataFormat();
  console.log(result);
}

dataResult()
```

And got this error:

```
(node:11059) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'eachRow' of undefined
    at /Users/jasonharder/coding/projects/hvacdoctor/controllers/hvacdoctor.js:69:15
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

What is happening that I am missing?

Note: I have refactored the code a little bit - I am returning undefined now. 
Note: Appended where worksheet is defined (it is defined in the file)

Comment: the top line was on the same line as the code formatting marks (`) I guess that line is invisible but it was also the line with the function name.

Comment: Your first attempt logs nothing because you never actually call the anonymous function at the end (did you mean to do (async () => { ... })()`?). The second attempt throws an error because `dataFormat` expects two arguments, `worksheet` and `rowNumber`, but you call it with no arguments (`await dataFormat()`), so `worksheet` is undefined when you try to call `worksheet.eachRow`.

Comment: There are other problems with your code, though. In particular, the callback passed to `csvWorkbook.then` is `async`, but you never call `await` inside it, and you also never return a value from it. You also never return a value from `dataFormat`. Please don't take this the wrong way, but this code feels a bit like you've just peppered `async`/`await`s around your code without really understanding the relationship between that pattern and Promises.

Comment: What's the purpose of the outermost `rowNumber` argument? You never use it. And what's the purpose of `csvWorkbook`? You do this: `await csvWorkbook.then(async function(result) { ...`, but then you never use `result`.

Comment: csvWorkbook is the file that needs to be read by the excel library and its returned values are what I'm working with.

Comment: Please see my other comments. You're still not passing a `worksheet` argument to `dataFormat`, so you're going to get an error when you try `worksheet.eachRow`. Did you mean to use the resolved value of `csvWorkbook` instead, e.g. `csvWorkbook.then(result => result.eachRow...`? And you're still not returning any value from `dataFormat` or the callback you pass to `csvWorkbook.then` (you need `return` statements, e.g. `return csvWorkbook.then...` and `return thermostatRows.map...`).

Comment: P.S. To format multi-line blocks of code on Stack Overflow, [indent it four spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) or highlight it and click on the "`{}`" button. Backticks (`\``) only work for `inline code`.

Comment: A worksheet is carried over from a previous function where I've defined it - I don't know if that's what you're referring to but I do get an error that it's already defined when I call it in the formatData() function.

Comment: Your `formatData` function takes an argument named `worksheet`, but you’re calling `formatData()` with no arguments, so *inside your function* `worksheet` is undefined, regardless of what `worksheet` outside the function is. You either need to remove the argument named `worksheet` or you need to call `formatData(worksheet)`.